# Cleaning a plate using your finger

Tags: verbs

What should be the verb for the action if someone takes the sauce, mayonnaise or curry on the plate with his finger into his mouth? The purpose is to consume it totally.

to clean the plate with finger

to clean off the plate with finger

[image]

Comment: Your title asks about "licking" or "cleaning", but your examples have "clean" and "clean off". Please edit your question to clarify what you're actually asking.

Comment: @ MarcInManhattan  Done

Comment: ...used his finger(s) to wipe the plate clean?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one verb that covers the entire action described. I think your best option is to describe the action, for example:

> He enjoyed the meal so much he made sure to get every last drop,
> running his finger along the plate for any missed morsels.

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct and easily understood, but I believe that "clean" is somewhat more common than "clean off" (at least here in the Northeast U.S.).

Also, "finger" would need a determiner. For example:

> She cleaned the plate with her finger.

(Of course, this doesn't indicate that she actually ate the food.)

Comment: @ MarcInManhattan She not cleaned the plate but also ate the sauce, etc that she got on her finger from the plate, now what should be used?

Comment: Cleaning the plate implies that everything was removed from the plate, including any sauce. You can say that she "licked her fingers" (or "licked her fingers clean") to include that action.